# Embedding of some rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

For me, a **projective variety** is an irreducible closed subset of some $P_K^n$ (with Zariski topology) where $K$ si an algebraically closed field.

If $X\subseteq P_K^n$ is a projective variety, then the quotient $R(X)=K[x_0,\dots,x_n]/I(X)$ is the **projective coordinate ring of $X$**, where $I(X)$ is the ideal generated by the homogeneous polynomial that vanish on $X$. Let $U$ be a non empty open subset of $X$, let $f\colon U\to K$ be a function. I say that $f$ is **regular in $a\in U$** if there exists an open subset $V$ of $U$ such that $a\in V$ and exist $h,k \in R(X)$, homogeneous of the same degree, such that $f_{|V}=\frac{h}{k}_{|V}$ and $k(y)\neq 0$ for all $y\in V$. I say that $f$ is **regular in $U$** if $f$ is regular in all point of $U$. Then, $O_X(U)$ is the ring ($K$-algebra) of the regular functions in $U$. [Note that $R(X)$ is also a **graded ring** because $K[x_0,\dots,x_n]$ is a graded ring and $I(X)$ is an homogeneous ideal; and $R(X)$ is also an **integral domain** because $I(X)$ is a prime ideal, because $X$ is irreducible.]

So $O_X(X)$ is the ring of the regular functions in all $X$.

For me, $R(X)_{(x_i)}$ is the **homogeneous localization** of $R(X)$ with respect to the multiplicatively closed subset $S=\{ x_i^n\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, i.e. $R(X)_{(x_i)}$ is the subring of zero-degree of the graded ring $S^{-1}R(X)$.

For me, $R(X)_{((0))}$ is the **homogeneous localization** of $R(X)$ with respect to the complement of the prime ideal $(0)$ of $R(X)$, i.e. $R(X)_{((0))}$ is the subring of zero-degree of the graded ring $S^{-1}R(X)$, where $S=\{\text{non-zero homogeneous elements  of $R(X)$}\}$.

For me, Quot$R(X)$ is the **field of fractions** of the integral domain $R(X)$.

Finally, $M$ is the localization $S^{-1}R(X)$ where $S=\{\text{non-zero homogeneous elements  of $R(X)$}\}$. Then $M$ is an $R(X)$-algebra.

My question is

> How can i define **embeddings** between the above rings such that i can consider $$O_X(X)\subseteq \bigcap_{0\le i\le n}R(X)_{(x_i)}\subseteq R(X)_{((0))}\subseteq M\subseteq \text{Quot}R(X) \qquad \qquad (1)$$

I would like to have the precise and rigorous definition of the various embeddings needed for having $(1)$.

**Please** do not use the fact that $O_X(X)\simeq K$ because i have to prove it using the above embeddings.

**P.S.**: I know that $R(X)_{(x_i)}\simeq O_X(X_i)$ where $X_i:=X\cap U_i$ where $U_i=P_k^n\setminus Z(x_i)$ , where $Z(x_i)$ is the zero locus of the homogeneous polynomial $x_i\in K[x_0,\dots,x_n]$, and i have that $$f\in O_X(X) \mapsto f_{|X_i}\in O_X(X_i)$$ and i believe this map is injective.

Comment: Try to simplify a little and start with a graded ring $R$ which is also an integral domain.

Comment: @user26857 If $R$ is a graded ring which is also an integral domain, and $f\in R$ is an homogeneous element, then i have $$\iota_f \colon\frac{a}{f^n} \in R_{(f)}\mapsto \frac{a}{f^n}\in R_{((0))}$$, where $a$ is an homogeneous element of $R$ of degree$=n*deg(f)$.

Then i define $$\iota\colon \frac{a}{b}\in R_{((0))}\mapsto \frac{a}{b}\in M$$.

Then i define $$\iota_M \colon \frac{a}{b}\in M \mapsto \frac{a}{b}\in \text{Quot}R$$. In this way i have embeddings $$R_{(f)}\subseteq R_{((0))}\subseteq M\subseteq \text{Quot}R$$, right?

Comment: @user26857 I think i have problem with the part $$O_X(X)\subseteq \bigcap_{0\le i\le n} R(X)_{(x_i)}\subseteq R(X)_{((0))}$$ , i.e. to embed $O_X(X)$ in $R(X)_{((0))}$.

Comment: @user26857 In my first comment, i have $\iota_M \circ \iota \circ \iota_f=\gamma_f$ where $$\gamma_f\colon \frac{a}{f^n}\in R_{(f)}\mapsto\frac {a}{f^n}\in \text{Quot}(R)$$.

How can i define $$\alpha\colon O_X(X)\to R(X)_{((0))}$$ and $$\alpha_i\colon O_X(X)\to R(X)_{(x_i)}$$ such that $\beta_i\circ \alpha_i=\alpha$ where $$\beta_i\colon \frac{g}{x_i^n}\in R(X)_{(x_i)}\mapsto \frac{g}{x_i^n}\in R(X)_{((0))}$$

Comment: @Minato [Crossposting](https://mathoverflow.net/q/287274/19965), especially without acknowledgement that you are doing so is frowned upon. In some circumstances, where an on-topic question does not get an answer for a long time (meaning on the order of weeks or months, not hours or days) crossposting may be OK, but even then you have to try to draw attention to the fact, and perhaps eventually delete one of the copies.

Comment: @rschwieb thank you for the advise. Is it ok if a will delete the one which didn't get an answer after that the other got an answer? I thought there were more probabilities to get an answer on the other community, so i posted it there. In what sense can one "draw attention to the fact"?  I thought that after a couple of days a question "disappear" because of newer questions so it is more and more difficult that the question could get an answer. Or am i wrong?  Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Minato To draw attention to the fact you are crossposting, say "I also posted this question at ____"